# Combinations of 15 scoops from 5 flavours?

Tags: combinatorics

The order of flavours does not matter, ie AAA...AB is considered the same as BAA...AAA due to having the same ingredients. I I want to use the combination formula but it leads to a negative factorial. Sorry if the question is trivial but I haven't found any solutions.

The final answer should be the total number of orderings possible (not necessarily in a numerical form).

Comment: What do you mean when you say it leads to a negative factorial?  Can you show us your computations?

Comment: It isn't trivial.  [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) gives you the ways to count the ordered $5-$tuples of non-negative integers that add to $15$.   I believe that is what you want here.

Comment: I'm using the equation of n! / r!(n-r)! where n objects are taken r at a time. I'm using n as 5 and r as 15 leading to (-10)!

Comment: Just to clarify:  "ordered" here refers to the flavors of ice cream, not the order of the scoops.  Thus the $5-$tuple $(6,7,1,0,1)$ means "$6$ scoops of vanilla, $7$ of chocolate, 1 each of strawberry and coffee.   It does not tell you how to arrange them (nor, I think, do you want it to).

Comment: When you choose (i.e. use the binomial formula), you are choosing without replacement, which means that you can't choose more scoops than you have flavours.  In this case, that can't happen.  @lulu gives the right idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is what is wanted here.

Specifically, you want to count the ordered $5-$tuples of non-negative integers that sum to $15$.  If, say, you had the $5-$tuple $(3,2,5,1,4)$ that would tell you how many scoops of each sort to use.  That is $3$ vanilla, $2$ chocolate, and so on.  How you distribute those $15$ scoops is then up to you.

As the link explains, the general formula for counting the $k-$tuples of non-negative integers that sum to $n$ is $\binom {n+k-1}n$.  Here we get $$\boxed {\binom {15+5-1}{15}=\binom {19}{15}=3876}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how many combinations you can have if each flavor must be different and the order is important than you need ${15 \choose 5}$ which is $\frac{15!}{(15-5)!5!}= \frac{15*14*13*12*11*10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2}{10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*5*4*3*2} = \frac{15*14*13*12*11}{5*4*3*2} = \frac{360360}{120} = 3003$

Comment: This is not what is being asked.  We want to know how many different ways a total of $15$ scoops can be ordered if $5$ flavors are available, that is, we need the number of solutions of the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 15$$ in the nonnegative integers, where $x_k$ is the number of scoops of flavor $k$ that are ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Just to unroll "[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))" a little more, you observed that the order is not important, so we can set a fixed order for the various flavours, then choose when to transition from one flavour to the next. $\newcommand{tn}{\ \! \color{red}{|}\ \!}$

So suppose the flavours are vanilla, strawberry, chocolate, orange and mango - $v,s,c,o,m$ respectively. Then an example combination might be $$vvssssccoooooom$$
or indicating the transitions with $\tn$ from one flavour to the next $$vv\tn ssss\tn cc\tn oooooo\tn m$$
and also since I have fixed the order of flavours, we don't need to see each flavour code and $$xx\tn xxxx\tn xx\tn xxxxxx\tn x$$ carries the same information. Consecutive transitions would mean that a given flavour is absent, as would leading or trailing transitions, so these are all valid possibilities. For example an all-orange option would look like $$\tn \tn \tn xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\tn $$

So we have to place $4$ transitions in a string of $19$ characters, giving $\binom {19}{4} = \frac{19!}{15!\cdot 4!}$ different "recipes" of flavour combinations. And we get $19$ from the $5$ flavours needing $5-1=4$ transitions among the $15$ scoops, so the string is $15+5-1$ characters long.